# SQL Server Express 2008 R2 installation on Windows Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, installation, windows-server-2008-r2

I have installed Windows Server 2008R2x64 under VMWare Workstation, to test installation of my application. I then installed the .Net 4.0 distributables and then SQL Server Express 2008 R2 SP1 (`SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe` from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22973). I accepted all defaults and including the default instance `SQLExpress`.

When I can start the management console, `SQLEXpress` is not available as an instance.

In `Administrative Tools > Services`, SQL Server is running, with instance `SQLServer`. I have enabled the Agent and Browser services.

This is killing me as I need to install at a customer site on Monday...

Any ideas?

Comment: What management console are you using to try opening the instance? Have you installed SQL Server Management Studio? Can you open "SQL Server Configuration Manager (Start -> All Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 -> Configuration Tools) and confirm the instance name? Have you configured user rights to the SQL Server (Windows Authentication or SQL Login)? And lastly, are you an Administrator on your machine?

Comment: Instance "SQLServer" seems to indicate a full version of SQL Server - as does the Agent service - SQL Server Express doesn't have an Agent service......

Comment: I am using SQL Management Studio, that gets installed as part of the SQLServer installation. I can open the Configuration Tools.  It says Configuration Tools(local) in the title when I do.  I used Windows authentication, and yes, I am Admin.

Comment: @marc_S - I think you are wrong and SQLServer Express does have an Agent service, I see it right on my dev machine, where I have SQL Server Express installed.

Comment: @GilShalit: go check out the [official Microsoft edition comparison](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/compare.aspx) and select "Express" and "Standard" and then look in the "Management Tools" section - SQL Server Express **DOES NOT** have SQL Server Agent .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like all that was required was a restart.  After that I was able to browse to the instance...